# How to add item to array in struct in golang

Tags: arrays, struct, go

With the code below how do I add an IP struct to the Server struct's ips array?

```
import (
    "net"
)

type Server struct {
    id int
    ips []net.IP
}

func main() {
    o := 5
    ip := net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")
    server := Server{o, ??ip??}
}
```

Do I even have the ips array correct? Is it better to use a pointer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A slice literal looks like `[]net.IP{ip}` (or `[]net.IP{ip1,ip2,ip3...}`. Stylistically, struct initializers with names are preferred, so `Server{id: o, ips: []net.IP{ip}}` is more standard. The whole code sample with those changes:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

type Server struct {
    id  int
    ips []net.IP
}

func main() {
    o := 5
    ip := net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")
    server := Server{id: o, ips: []net.IP{ip}}
    fmt.Println(server)
}
```

You asked

> Do I even have the ips array correct? Is it better to use a pointer?

You don't need to use a pointer to a slice. Slices are little structures that *contain* a pointer, length, and capacity.

Comment: about the "initializers with names" what do you with anonymous struct in the struct

Comment: If you're talking about [type embedding](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding), you use the name of the embedded type as the field name in the initializer (e.g., http://play.golang.org/p/CG1u8AOWOe).

Comment: ahhh now i think i understand the table-testing examples in the fmt package. it's like we have to sacrifice the clarity of JSON for having a nice programming language. and that's ok.